# circular grid radar and scale max/min not working - chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to set min/max starting values to scale and circular grid to a radar in chartjs, but none seens to work.

```
const chart1 = new Chart($('#chart-area1'), {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '1',
            data: [20, 25, 55],
            borderColor: setup_borderColor[0],
            backgroundColor: setup_backgroundColor[0],
            borderWidth: 1
        },{
            label: '2',
            data: [25, 35, 40],
            borderColor: setup_borderColor[1],
            backgroundColor: setup_backgroundColor[1],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scale: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
        },
        scales: {
            r: {
                grid: {
                    circular: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The radar chartjs should start at 0 with a max value at 100 and be a circular grid, but both options dont work, my result:

Result:

[image]

Chartjs version: Chart.js v2.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing V2 and V3 syntax in all the wrong ways, in V2 you need to use the `scale` option not `scales.r` and the min/max have to be configured in the `ticks` part not in the root and grid must be gridLines:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        max: 40,
        min: 0
      },
      gridLines: {
        circular: true
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

For more info you can read the 2.9.4 [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/)